# Drop Index if exsists... create if exists

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Before dropping and creating an index I would like to check if the index exists.

Is that possible with a simple 1-2 row statement?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly query `dba_indexes`/ `all_indexes`/ `user_indexes` to see if the index exists.  Assuming you want to look for a particular index name (you could also match on the set of columns)

```
select count(*)
  into l_cnt
  from all_indexes
 where owner = <<owner of index>>
   and index_name = <<name of index>>

if( l_cnt > 0 )
then
  <<index exists>>
else
  <<index doesn't exist>>
end if;
```

Of course, you could also simply drop the index and catch the exception that it doesn't exist.

Comment: it is not possible to do something like "Create Index <Name> if exsits <Indexname>"? If not ill stick to your first answer ;)

Comment: @user2428207 - There is no such thing as a conditional DDL statement, no.

Comment: @user2428207, just drop the index - if the index doesn't exist, it will raise an exception that you can catch.